# Authenticating with user/password *once* for multiple commands? (session multiplexing)

Tags: bash, ssh, sftp, scp, openssh

I got this trick from Solaris documentation, for copying `ssh` public keys to remote hosts.

*note: `ssh-copy-id` isn't available on Solaris*

```
$ cat some_data_file | ssh user@host "cat >/tmp/some_data_file; some_shell_cmd"
```

I wanted to adapt it to do more involved things.

Specifically I wanted *`some_shell_command`* to be a script sent from the *local* host to execute on the *remote* host... a script would interact with the *local* keyboard (e.g. prompt user when the script was running on the remote host).

I experimented with ways of sending multiple things over `stdin` from multiple sources.  But certain things that work in in *local* shell don't work over ssh, and some things, such as the following, didn't do what I wanted at all:

```
$ echo "abc" | cat <(echo "def")     # echoes: def  (I wanted abc\ndef)
$ echo "abc" | cat  < <(echo "def")  # echoes: def  (I wanted abc\ndef)

$ echo "abc" | cat <<-EOF
> echo $(</dev/stdin)   #echoes: echo abc  (I wanted: abc) 
> EOF

# messed with eval for the above but that was a problem too.
```

[@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) concluded it's not feasible to do all of that in a single `ssh` command. He suggested a theoretical alternative that didn't work as hoped, but I got it working after some research and tweaking and documented the results of that and posted it as an answer to this question.

Without that solution, having to run multiple `ssh`, and `scp` commands by default entails being prompted for password multiple times, which is a major drag.

I can't expect all the users of a script I write in a multi-user environment to configure public key authorization, nor expect they will put up with having to enter a password over and over.

Comment: It's easy to see why `echo "abc" | cat <(echo "def") ` doesn't work, `cat` will only listen on stdin if no command-line arguments are provided or only  `-` is provided.

Comment: But stdin is coming from two places, or at least is described as being sourced from two places.

Comment: What do you mean? `<(command)` is process substitution, it will evaluate to the path to a file descriptor, try running `echo <(command)`, from `cat`'s POV, it's the same as calling it on any other file.

Comment: So are you saying it's not to be thought of as redirecting the echo output to `cat's` stdin?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work that way. It basically creates a file descriptor and redirects the `command`'s stdout to it and then evaluates to the path to that file descriptor, so it's the same as calling `cat /path/to/file`. Lookup process substitution.

Comment: What does it mean that "_command_ is to be sourced from the local side"?

Comment: `ssh` only creates one path from the local host to the remote host, and that's via `ssh`'s standard input. I don't think you can do what you want with one command, but you *can* run multiple `ssh` clients that share the same connection via a socket. See `man ssh_config` and search for `ControlMaster`.

Comment: @dramzy but `echo "abc" | cat < <(echo def)` does the same thing

Comment: That's probably because the file redirection is overriding the pipeline redirection. [See this SO question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Comment: Unlike `cat`, `ssh` does not read commands from a local file to execute remotely, so process substitution isn't going to help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### **OpenSSH Session Multiplexing**

---

*This solution works even when using earlier versions of OpenSSH where the

     `ControlPersist`option isn't available. (Working bash example at end of this answer)*

---

<sub>*Note: [OpenSSH 3.9](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-3.9) introduced Session Multiplexing over a "control master connection" (in 2005), However, the `ControlPersist` option wasn't introduced until  [OpenSSH 5.6](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.6) (released in 2010)*.</sub>

ssh session multiplexing allows a script to authenticate once and do multiple ssh transactions over the authenticated connection. For example, if you have a script that runs several distinct tasks using `ssh`, `scp`, or `sftp`, each transaction can be carried out over `OpenSSH` 'control master session' that refers to location of its named-socket in the filesystem.

The following one-time-password authentication is useful when running a script that has to perform *multiple* ssh operations and one wants to avoid users having to password authenticate more than once, and is especially useful in cases where public key authentication  isn't viable - e.g. not permitted, or at least not configured.

---

[image]

---

Most solutions I've seen entail using `ControlPersist` to tell `ssh` to keep the control master connection open, either indefinitely, or for some specific number of seconds.

Unfortunately, systems with OpenSSH prior to 5.6 don't have that option (wherein upgrading them might not be feasible). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be much documentation or discussion about *that* limitation online.

Reading through old release docs I discovered `ControlPersist` arrived late in the game for `ssh` session multiplexing scene. implying there may have been an alternative way to configure session multiplexing without relying on the `ControlPersist` option prior to it.

Initially trying to configure persistent-sessions from command line options rather than the config parameter,  I ran into the problem of the ssh session terminating prematurely, closing control connection client sessions with it, or, alternatively, the connection was held open (kept ssh control master alive), terminal I/O was blocked, and the script would hang.

The following clarifies how to accomplish it.

---

```
OpenSSH option            ssh flag          Purpose
-------------------       ---------         -----------------------------
-o ControlMaster=yes      -M                Establishes sharable connection
-o ControlPath=path       -S path           Specifies path of connection's named socket
-o ControlPersist=600                       Keep shareable connection open 10 min.
-o ControlPersist=yes                       Keep shareable connection open indefinitely
                          -N                Don't create shell or run a command
                          -f                Go into background after authenticating
                          -O exit           Closes persistent connection
```

```
ControlPersist form       Equivalent        Purpose
-------------------       ----------------  -------------------------
-o ControlPersist=yes     ssh -Nf           Keep control connection open indefinitely
-o ControlPersist=300     ssh -f sleep 300  Keep control connection open 5 min.
```

<sup>*Note: `scp` and `sftp` implement `-S` flag differently, and `-M` flag not at all, so, for those commands, the `-o option` form is always required.*</sup>

---

**Sketchy Overview of Operations:**
<sub>*Note: This incomplete example doesn't execute as shown.*</sub>

```
ctl=<path to dir to store named socket>
ssh -fNMS $ctl user@host      # open control master connection
ssh -S $ctl …                 # example of ssh over connection
scp  -o ControlPath=$ctl …    # example of scp over connection
sftp -o ControlPath=$ctl …    # example of sftp over connection
ssh -S $ctl -O exit           # close control master connection
```

---

**Session Multiplexing Demo**

*(Try it. You'll like it. Working example - authenticates only once):*

Running this script will probably help you understand it quicker than reading it, and it is fascinating.

*Note: If you lack access to remote host, just enter localhost at the "Host...?" prompt if you want to try this demo script*

```
#!/bin/bash       # This script demonstrates ssh session multiplexing

trap "[ -z "$ctl" ] || ssh -S $ctl -O exit $user@$host" EXIT # closes conn, deletes fifo

read -p "Host to connect to? " host
read -p "User to login with? " user

BOLD="\n$(tput bold)"; NORMAL="$(tput sgr0)"

echo -e "${BOLD}Create authenticated persistent control master connection:${NORMAL}"

sshfifos=~/.ssh/controlmasters

[ -d $sshfifos ] || mkdir -p $sshfifos; chmod 755 $sshfifos

ctl=$sshfifos/$user@$host:22 # ssh stores named socket ctrl conn here

ssh -fNMS $ctl $user@$host  # Control Master: Prompts passwd then persists in background

lcldir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/XXXX)

echo -e "\nLocal  dir: $lcldir"

rmtdir=$(ssh -S $ctl $user@$host "mktemp -d /tmp/XXXX")

echo      "Remote dir: $rmtdir"

echo -e "${BOLD}Copy self to remote with scp:${NORMAL}"

scp -o ControlPath=$ctl ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} $user@$host:$rmtdir 

echo -e "${BOLD}Display 4 lines of remote script, with ssh:${NORMAL}"
echo "====================================================================="
echo $rmtdir | ssh -S $ctl $user@$host "dir=$(</dev/stdin); head -4 \$dir/*"
echo "====================================================================="

echo -e "${BOLD}Do some pointless things with sftp:${NORMAL}"
sftp -o ControlPath=$ctl $user@$host:$rmtdir <<EOF
    pwd
    ls
    lcd $lcldir
    get *
    quit
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a master control socket, you can use multiple processes without having to authenticate more than once. This is just a simple example; see `man ssh_config` under `ControlPath` for advice on using a more secure socket.

It's not quite clear what you mean by sourcing `somecommand` locally; I'm going to assume it is a local script that you want copied over to the remote host. The simplest thing to do is just copy it over to run it.

```
# Copy the first file, and tell ssh to keep the connection open
# in the background after scp completes
$ scp -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPersist=yes -o ControlPath=%C somefile user@host:/tmp/somefile
# Copy the script on the same connection
$ scp -o ControlPath=%C somecommand user@host:
# Run the script on the same connection
$ ssh -o ControlPath=%C user@host somecommand
# Close the connection
$ ssh -o ControlPath=%C -O exit user@host
```

Of course, the user could use public key authentication to avoid entering their credentials *at all*, but `ssh` would still go through the authentication process each time. Here, the authentication process is only done *once*, by the command using `ControlMaster=yes`. The other two processes reuse that connection. The last commmand, with `-O exit`, doesn't actually connect; it just tells the local connection to close itself.

Comment: That was close to the right answer but didn't work for me 'out of the box'. Probably because I'm using an earlier openssh than you are. So I added an answer to show how I resolved it based on your great information.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "abc" | cat <(echo "def")
```

The expression `<(echo "def")` expands to a file name, typically something like `/dev/fd/63`, that names a (virtual) file containing the text `"def"`. So lets's simplify it a bit:

```
$ echo "def" > def.txt
$ echo "abc" | cat def.txt
```

This will also prints just `def`.

The pipe *does* feed the line `abc` to the standard input of the `cat` command. But because `cat` is given a file name on its command line, *it doesn't read from its standard input*.  The `abc` is just quietly ignored, and the `cat` command prints the contents of the named file -- which is exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: But I get the same result with `echo "abc" | cat < <(echo def)`

Comment: Yes, that was my point. I realize my answer is incomplete; I explained how the command works, but not good to fix it so it does what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciated the answer I was just coming to terms with the implementation and implication.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `echo abc | cat <(echo def)` is that the `<()` wins the "providing the input" race.  Luckily, bash will allow you to supply many inputs using mulitple `<()` constructs.  So the trick is, how do you get the output of your `echo abc` into the `<()`?

How about:

```
    $ echo abc | cat <(echo def) <(cat)
    def
    abc
```

If you need to handle the input from the pipe first, just switch the order:

```
    $ echo abc | cat <(cat) <(echo def)
    abc
    def
```